# How to redirect to another view/page if the form is invalid

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

In the event that the form is not valid, how do I redirect the user to another page?

```
def dothings(request):
    
    form = dumyForm(request.POST or None)
    
    if form.is_valid():    
        #do 123    
    else:   
      # INSTEAD OF REINITIALIZING THE FORM LIKE THIS, I WANT TO REDIRECT TO ANOTHER PAGE
      form = form = dumyForm()
    
   return render(request,'dummy.html',{})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this :

```
def dothings(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = dumyForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():    
            **other_code**
            return redirect('redirect_page_view')

        else:
            return redirect('redirect_page_view')
    else:   
        form = dumyForm()

 context = {'form':form}
 return render(request,'dummy.html',context)
```

Comment: I want to redirect if the form is NOT valid

Comment: Updated my Answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to redirect the user to another page, you can use the following line: `return HttpResponseRedirect('page/')`, where 'page' is the URL of your other page.

Comment: this line: `return render(request,'dummy.html',{})` will be inreachable

Comment: aqpcserver, this line is reachable when request method is not POST (usually is GET)